# Bluemix DashDB WHERE IN statement not working

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-cloud, db2-luw, dashdb

I am developing an IBM Bluemix solution using Node-RED with DashDB. I am facing an issue when parsing the multiple values to an column called `ACCOUNT_ID` on a `WHERE IN` SQL clause. If I just pass one parameter it works perfectly but when I have two or more it fails with the folliwng error message:

```
msg.account = msg.req.query.account;
msg.datestart = msg.req.query.datestart;
msg.dateend = msg.req.query.dateend;
var strPayload = "SELECT A.*, B.DESCRIPTION AS ACCOUNT_NAME, C.DESCRIPTION AS TYPE_NAME ";
strPayload += " FROM NORMALIZED_TABLE A ";
strPayload += " INNER JOIN ACCOUNT B ON A.ACCOUNT_ID = B.ACCOUNT_ID ";
strPayload += " INNER JOIN NORMALIZED_TYPE C ON A.TYPE_ID = C.TYPE_ID";
strPayload += " WHERE A.ACCOUNT_ID IN(?) AND DATE_START>=? AND DATE_END<=?";
strPayload += " FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY";
msg.payload = strPayload;
return msg;
```

Basically my problem is here: `WHERE A.ACCOUNT_ID IN(?)`. With a single value, the webservice is invoked and it works fine as below:

```
/getPreviewReport?datestart=2016-08-01&dateend=2016-08-01&account=44
```

But when I pass multiple values for the account parameter as below, it fails:

```
/getPreviewReport?datestart=2016-08-01&dateend=2016-08-01&account=44,45,2
```

Node-red Error:

> dashDB query node: Error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0420N Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECIMAL". SQLSTATE=22018

How can I reslove this problem?

Comment: This is more a SQL question than a specifically Bluemix one. I have added the SQL tag so that more people will see it.

Comment: I disagree with you Ralpherle because once I run the same command under SQL command line directly it works perfectly but the same does not occurs under dashdb and node-red.

Comment: The point of retagging is to get as many eyes on the question as possible to get a good answer. A person with advanced knowledge of SQL might be able to troubleshoot for you. Also adding the DashDB tag, though I'm not certain it's specific to this service.

Comment: One parameter marker -- one value. If you want to pass a variable list of values to the `IN` predicate you will have to build the query string dynamically (opening you to the SQL injection possibility, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Any SQL database that I know of will treat anything supplied as a bind variable value as exactly that -- single value -- without any parsing.

A common way to deal with variable-length `IN` lists is to use dynamic SQL, which, unfortunately, is prone to SQL injection attacks, especially in scenarios like yours where you pass unsanitized HTTP request properties directly into the query.

You can add a bit of safety by using recursive SQL to parse the parameter string, like so:

```
-- parse comma-separated values into a "table"
WITH lst (lvl, id, tail) AS (  
  SELECT 1, CASE WHEN LOCATE(',',input) > 0 
              THEN TRIM(LEFT(input, LOCATE(',',input)-1))
              ELSE TRIM(input) 
         END,    
         CASE WHEN LOCATE(',',input) > 0 
              THEN SUBSTR(input, LOCATE(',',input)+1)    
              ELSE '' 
         END  
  FROM table (values ?) as (input)
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT lvl + 1, CASE WHEN LOCATE(',', tail) > 0 
              THEN TRIM(LEFT(tail, LOCATE(',', tail)-1))    
              ELSE TRIM(tail) 
         END,    
         CASE WHEN LOCATE(',', tail) > 0 
              THEN SUBSTR(tail, LOCATE(',', tail)+1)    
              ELSE '' 
         END
  FROM lst 
  WHERE lvl < 100 AND tail != '')

SELECT a.*, b.description as account_name, c.description as type_name 
 FROM normalized_table a
 INNER JOIN account b ON a.account_id = b.account_id 
 INNER JOIN normalized_type c ON a.type_id = c.type_d
 -- join to the parameter "table" on id
 INNER JOIN lst ON a.account_id = lst.id
 WHERE date_start>=? AND date_nd<=?
 FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY
```